# Eureka Server Error EurekaClientAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

[Eureka error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lzfyu.png)

> build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
        springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.RC2'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.ragavan'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

> Application

```
package com.ragavan.discovery;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class DiscoveryServerApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServerApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your `pom.xml` and your `Application` class.

Comment: I have added the gradle file and application class

Comment: I'm not familiar with Gradle, but you can have a look at this [build.gradle](https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/) in Spring getting started tutorial.

Comment: Have you resolved issue? I have the same

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue : 
"No qualifying bean of type'org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment'"

I have used STS + maven in a spring boot project so updating the project with "Force update with snapshot release" will resolve the issue.

[image: update dependencies]

Also check if the port is not already in use

In application.properties

```
spring.application.name=server
server.port=8761
```

The server will start on port as shown below:

[image: Server started screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Same issue was coming with 2.1.4.RELEASE also. but it resolved with 2.1.5.RELEASE.